# Thyme leaf not rendering with spring mvc

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

Hello i'm new to spring and i'm trying to display a simple html file with thymeleaf but have problem rendering the view. It only displays the string "index" but not the html contents in index.html. Please could someone tell me what i did wrong

```
web.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Hotel Management System</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

dispatcher-servle.xml file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.myExample.controller" />

       <bean class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" />
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
       <bean name="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
           <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates"/>
           <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
           <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
        </bean>

        <bean name="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
            <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>
       <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

TestController.java:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String printWelcome() {

        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.html file: defined in webapp/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5
   elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the
   page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/
3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/
1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>

        .box {

            background-color:#d3d3d3

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>

        <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>

    </div>


</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/
jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) would be valuable for a few reasons I think.

Comment: If you're new to Spring, start with Spring Boot and a basic starter project (with Web and Thymeleaf) from https://start.spring.io.

Comment: @chrylis i wanted to understand xml configurations and have more control

Comment: Best of luck if you are wanting to learn XML, but it's obsolete.

Comment: @chrylis ok. What about doing the configurations in Java

Comment: I would suggest looking at the `ThymeleafAutoConfiguration` in Spring Boot. It shows how to do it. (Or just use the autoconfiguration.)

Answer (score 15):

Change the @RestController annotation to @Controller annotation. The Rest Controller is String specific.

Comment: That was my problem 
+1